# Using an old penalized domain for a new website

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect, google-penguin-algorithm

I had a website with 2 domains like these: `firstdomain.com` and `first-domain.com`.

The main domain was `first-domain.com` and the other one was 301 redirected to first one.
The main domain got a Google Penguin penalty some months ago. I uploaded the site on an new domain and removed Google index of old domain by using the remove URL tool in Webmaster Tools. Now, I want to use `firstdomain.com` (which was redirected to the penalized domain) for a new and fresh website with new and perfect content.

Is it probable that history of this domain affects the new website and harms its ranking?

Comment: Just to clarify, firstdomain.com was redirected to first-domain.com but first-domain.com was the one that got slapped?

Comment: yes, exactly! firstdomain.com was 301 redirected to first-domain.com but first-domain.com was penalized. An another point is firstdomain.com (which was redirected) has same page rank as first-domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would see what links are pointing to `firstdomain.com`. If you got a Google Penguin adjustment because of bad links pointing to first-domain.com then that wont affect `firstdomain.com`, unless the same links also point there too. If `firstdomain.com` is free of links because it was never marketed then you would be pretty safe from Penguin .

Comment: Thanks a lot, but an important point is that in Webmaster Tools panel, there is no any external link reported pointing to firstdomain.com, even just one link, but firstdomain.com has same Google pagerank (PR 4) as first-domain.com! Its what I'm worried about!

Comment: Maybe you see the pagerank 4 when it is pointed at the other domain, if so - you could be seeing first-domain.com page rank.

Comment: Yeah, the point was logical if firstdomain.com was redirected to first-domain.com yet, but now, it is not redirected and has a same pagerank!

Comment: Do any other tools show links pointing to the site ? If you really cant find any bad links, especially not in Webmaster Tools then Penguin is not really a worry.